# i dont know where the syntax error that i have in json ionic

Tags: json.net

sorry for interrupt. can u help me.. i dont know where the syntax error that i have problem

the problem : ionic.bundle.js:25642 SyntaxError: Unexpected token ] in JSON at position 2882

the json :

```
{
"rawatanSemulajadi": [

            {
                "s_id" :"b004",
                "s_nama" :"zaitun",
                "s_perician" : "",
                "s_gambar":"img/delima.jpg"
            },
            {
                "s_id" :"b005",
                "s_nama" :"delima",
                "s_perician" : "",
                "s_gambar":""
            },
            {
                "s_id" :"b006",
                "s_nama" :"epal",
                "s_perician" :" ",
                "s_gambar":""
            },
            {
                "s_id" :"b007",
                "s_nama" :"labu manis",
                "s_perician" :"",
                "s_img":""
            },
            {
                "s_id" :"b008",
                "s_nama" :"tomato",
                "s_perician" :"",
                "s_gambar":""
            },
            {
                "s_id" :"b009",
                "s_nama" :"bawang",
                "s_perician" :"",
                "s_gambar":""
            },
            {
                "s_id" :"b010",
                "s_nama" :"habbatus sauda",
                "s_perician" :"",
                "s_gambar":""
            },
            {
                "s_id" :"b011",
                "s_nama" :"rizom",
                "s_perician" :"",
                "s_gambar":""

            },
            {
                "s_id" :"b012",
                "s_nama" :"peria",
                "s_perician" :" 1.**Paling cepat diproses dan diserap, sekaligus memberikan tenaga segera",
                "s_gambar":""

            },
            {
                "s_id" :"b013",
                "s_nama" :"pisang",
                "s_perician" :"",
                "s_gambar":""

            },
],
"penyakit":[   
            {
                "p_id" :"y111",
                "p_nama" :"cirit birit",
                "p_perician" : "",
                "p_gambar" : "",
                "s_id" : "b001, b003, b005, b009, b010"
            },
            {
                "p_id" :"y112",
                "p_nama" :"sembelit",
                "p_perician" : "",
                "p_gambar" : "",
                "s_id" :"b001, b002, b005, b006"
            },
            {

                "p_id" :"y113",
                "p_nama" :"demam",
                "s_id" :"b005, b006, b007, b009, b010"
            },
            {

                "p_id" :"y114",
                "p_nama" :"buasir",
                "p_perician" : "",
                "p_gambar" : "",
                "s_id" :"b004, b005, b010, b013"
            },
            {

                "p_id" :"y115",
                "p_nama" :"batuk",
                "p_perician" : "",
                "p_gambar" : "",
                "s_id" :"b003, b009, b010, b011"
            },
            {

                "p_id" :"y116",
                "p_nama" :"bisul",
                "p_perician" : "",
                "p_gambar" : "",
                "s_id" :"b004, b008, b009, b010, b012"
            },
            {

                "p_id" :"y117",
                "p_nama" :"sakit kepala",
                "p_perician" : "",
                "p_gambar" : "",
                "s_id" :"b002, b005, b011"
            },
            {

                "p_id" :"y118",
                "p_nama" :"luka",
                "p_perician" : "",
                "p_gambar" : "",
                "s_id" :"b002, b013"
            },
       ],

"tahapPenyakit":[   
            {
                "t_id" :"L1",
                "t_nama" :"ringan",
                "p_id" : "y111, y112, y113, y114, y115, y116, y117, y118"
            },
            {
                "t_id" :"L2",
                "t_nama" :"normal",
                "p_id" :"y111, y112, y113, y114, y115, y116, y117, y118"
            },
            {

                "t_id" :"L3",
                "t_nama" :"berat",
                "p_id" :"y111, y112, y113, y114, y115, y116, y117, y118"
            },
       ],

"cara":[
             {

                "p_id" :"y111",
                "s_id" :"b001, b003, b005, b009, b010",
                "c_ulasan" :""
            },
            {   
                "s_id" :"b002",
                "p_id" :"y112, y122, y114",
                "c_ulasan" :""

            },
            {
                "s_id" :"b003",
                "p_id" :"y111,y113, y114, y115, y116, y124",
                "c_ulasan" :" "

            },
            {
                "s_id" :"b004",
                "p_id" :"y118, y120,y121, y125",
                "c_ulasan" :""

            },
            {
                "s_id" :"b005",
                "p_id" :"y112, y113, y115, y117, y118, y120 ",
                "c_ulasan" :""

            },
            {
                "s_id" :"b006",
                "p_id" :"y114, y116",
                "c_ulasan" :""

            },
            {
                "s_id" :"b007",
                "p_id" :"y111, y112, y117, y124, y125",
                "c_ulasan" :""

            },
            {
                "s_id" :"b008",
                "p_id" :"y117",
                "c_ulasan" :""

            },
            {
                "s_id" :"b009",
                "p_id" :"y116",
                "c_ulasan" :""

            },
            {
                "s_id" :"b010",
                "p_id" :"y121",
                "c_ulasan" :""

            },
            {
                "s_id" :"b011",
                "p_id" :"y111, y119",
                "c_ulasan" :""

            },
            {
                "s_id" :"b012",
                "p_id" :"y111,  y114, y117, y118, y119, y120, y125",
                "c_ulasan" :""

            },
            {
                "s_id" :"b013",
                "p_id" :"y111, y119, y121, y122, y123",
                "c_ulasan" : ""

            }
        ]


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Everywhere you have this

```
        },
   ],
```

Is a syntax error. Remove the `,` after the `}`.